# Hibernate update database scheme - desync?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

We are using hibernate to map our entities to a database.

Yesterday we encountered a DataTruncationException, because a comment-field has not been anotated with a length.

We changed the entity and redeployed the application. Hibernate didn't alter the columns which is fine according to the docu. So we changed out database tables *manually* from a varchar(255) to longtext.

Now, the entities attribute is annotated with `@Column(length = 5000)` and the database column is of format longtext.

**The DataTruncationException still appears everytime**

We decided to export all the data, let hibernate create a fresh db, and insert the data again. This finally worked, and the problem has been resolved.

But we noticed, that hibernate ignores the hibernate_sequence->nextval entry and starts over with id 1. (Hibernate created a SECOND row in the hibernate_sequnce table, containing a 1)

After dropping that value and setting up the required id, everything seems to be fine.

But this raises two questions:

1. Why doesn't hibernate recocnize that the modified table now matches the entity?
2. Why does hibernate ignore the next_val on first run, and starts over again?